# How to stop R from automatically converting string to date?

Tags: r

I have a large excel file I'm reading into R for a sports analytics project. One of the columns is height, and the format *in excel* is ft-in (i.e. 5-10). This is fine in excel because that column was specifically formatted to take in plain text and not convert it to date. But when I read the csv to R, the data frame auto converts to date. Is there a command/parameter to have it not do this?

Comment: `help(read.csv)` or `help(read_csv)` depending on which you are using. For one you can use `as.is = TRUE` the other you probably use `col_types = 'c'`. Alternatively you could convert teh date after getting it into R.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that can be easily copy and pasted into anyone else's R session to reproduce the problem.  All library statements and inputs should be included.  Cut the problem down to the minimum that illustrates it.  Read the top of the [tag:r] tag page for more info.

Comment: Not sure how to provide a reproducible environment without also uploading my dataset. Literally the only thing in my environment is ```df <- read.csv('<path>')``` as.is=TRUE didn't seem to work unfortunately.